# vscode quickOpen existing "instance" of file in whatever Tab it is in

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say you have Tab X and Tab Y open. In Tab X you have `file1` and `file2` open, but `file2` is on top of the stack being rendered on the screen. In Tab Y you have other files open.

Now I'm currently focusing Tab Y and I open the quickOpen menu and select `file1` there. The vscode normal behavior is to open another "instance" of `file1` in Tab Y.

q1: Is there a way to change this behavior so I would just open the existing "instance" of `file1` in Tab X? I.e. move the focus to Tab X and move `file1` to the top of the stack.

q2: Is there a way to list all the **open files only** where you can fuzzy search names? I know quickOpen lists open files as well, but when working on a big project it is nice to be able to search only on already opened files.

The reason I'm asking is because this is how Intellij works. I find it easier to use multiple tabs and navigate between files when there is a single list of all open files regardless of which tab it is on and if you select a file from the list it just moves you to that file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q1: enable the setting `Workbench > Editor: Reveal If Open`

q2: I don't think you can search for a file within open files only.  The `Open Editors` view may be as close as you are going to get (see `Explorer > Open Editors: Visible`).  Perhaps there is an extension that does this.